# PHP, how to check for uppercase/lowercase/numbers/special in regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a class which validates parameters passed into a function, only primitive values though. I've so far done integer, boolean and float. However with my string function, I also want to be able to pass in a parameters about allowed character sets.
Like:

- Allowed upper case
- Allowed lower case
- Allowed numbers
- Allowed special characters

However, I can't figure out how to test this. I've tried doing it with regex, but my best trials aren't working too well.

Any nudge in the right direction would be a great help.

Please note, I'm using an old version for PHP - 5.1.2

Comment: Sorry. Yes, certainly have. I used multiplying prime numbers together for using multiple tags, then using modulo inside function to determine given flag. I've implemented all the min/max size code. Next time I will post what I've attempted.

Comment: @AlanMoore This is not a duplicate of the linked question. It has nothing to do with password strength. OP wants to check, if string consists of certain (allowed) characters as I understood the question.

Comment: @bobblebubble: You're right, I was hasty.  But the question is so basic, I don't think it's worth reopening, do you?  (No offense intended to the asker; it's not a *bad* question, but it's been asked many times already.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what specials. Can try this and use with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
preg_match('/^[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+$/', $str)
```

Check out [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oX8kY8/1)

- `[:alnum:]` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `[:punct:]` matches `[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_{|}~]` and backtick.
- `+` one ore more from `^` start to `$` end

[See more posix classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: Perfect, I'll be trying this out soon as I get back to a computer. I'll be marking it as right now though, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @JoshuaaM

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(!preg_match('/[.\s]/', $string))
{
  // it contains any single character except dot and white space
  // you can change not permitted list on your demand
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like it, I'll add some as this as flavour in my final regex string, thanks.

Comment: No problem, @JoshuaaM